# Unable to start an executable from Thunar

Tags: gnome, thunar, thunar-custom-actions

When I try to double click on an executable binary file to start a GUI program from *Thunar*, it throws the following error to *syslog* and does not start the program:

```
cannot open display: wayland-0
```

This happens in a **GNOME** desktop session, but not in a **GNOME Classic** session. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Note: This also prevents Thunar to start some custom actions (like *Search Monkey*).

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have been solved in Ubuntu 19.10 (Thunar version 1.8.9): After *upgrading* to Ubuntu 19.10, I no longer have **Wayland** in my login screen. So, I am using **GNOME on Xorg** by default.